# What do you call functions that are the $n$-th root of a degree $k$ polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, roots

What do you call functions that are the $n$-th root of a degree $k$ polynomial? i.e., functions of the form

$$f(x)=\sqrt[n]{a_0 + a_1x + \dots + a_kx^k}? $$

I was unable to explain to Google that I am not looking for an algorithm for finding zeros of polynomials.

Comment: Algebraic functions?

Comment: You have a problem, which is not the name of those functions. You reduced it (modelled it), or at least approached it by searching for that name. But what if that modelling is not useful? The name could not exist, or could not help you solve the original problem. Always post the original problem, without any "modelling".

Comment: Since $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{P(x)}$, with $P(x)$ a polynomial function of degree $k$, I would just name it an $n$-th root of a polynomial function.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Isn't that a larger class of functions?

Comment: *Isn't that a larger class of functions?* --- I don't think you'll find a more specific name that would be generally known (besides just calling it what it is) than [explicit algebraic function](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22explicit+algebraic+function%22), a strictly smaller class of functions than what @J. W. Tanner named. Even this, however, includes functions of vast complexity, such as an arithmetic and root combination generated from polynomials that could require years to write down in full.